# How to use textbox and ViewBag value in controller method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("sendcode", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
<div class="selected">You Selected:</div>
<div class="sname">@ViewBag.selectsong</div>
<div class="enter" style="width:458px;height:37px; text-align:left;">
<div class="selected">Enter your mobile number</div>
<div class="mobileno">
<div><div class="spann">+91</div><input name="MNumber" type="text" class="mobileinput"/></div></div>`enter code here`
<div class="confirm"><input name="" type="button" class="confirmb"value="Confirm"onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("getdetail", "Home" )'/>
</div>
<div class="applicablee">* charges applicable as per your mobile operators</div>
</div>
}
```

I want to use textbox value and ViewBag value on my controller method which has been defined below?

```
public string getdetail(string Mnumber, string sSongName)
{
    string ss = Mnumber;
    string ss1 = sSongName;
    return ss;
}
```

Comment: You can use hidden. Just add a hidden like `<input name="sSongName" type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.selectsong"/>`

Comment: Post back and the controller can pick them up.

Answer (score 0):

viewbag is a one way  property

if you want to return it value  you must define your variable as a property of your model
then pass the model as a parameter to your action

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fill your textbox with ViewBag value try this;

```
<input type="textbox" id="aa" name="aa" value="@Viewbag.X"/>
```

If you want to pass that value use hidden method **Satpal** mentioned about.